# A variation of Urysohn's lemma.

Tags: continuity, compactness

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^{N}$ be open and $K_1, K_2 \subseteq \Omega$ be compact subsets of $\Omega$ with $K_1 \cap K_2 = \varnothing.$ Then there exists a continuous function $f \in C_c (\Omega)$ with compact support contained in $\Omega$ such that $|f (x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$ and $f = 1$ on $K_1$ and $f = - 1$ on $K_2.$

This is almost an application of Urysohn's lemma except for the compactly supported part. Having obtained such a continuous function on $\Omega$ can we modify it further so that the resultant function is also bounded by $1$ and takes all the prescribed values on the compact sets and is compactly supported?

Comment: There exists a continuous function $g$ with support in $\Omega$ which is $1$ on $K_1\cup K_2$ with $|g| \leq 1$. Consider the product $fg$ where $f$ is the function given by Urysohn's Lemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The version of Urysohn's lemma that I'm using is Theorem 2.12 in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. It says:

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $U$ is open in $\Omega$, $K \subset U$ and $K$ is compact. Then there exists an $f \in C_c(X)$ such that
>
> - $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$.
> - $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in K$.
> - $\text{supp}(f)$ is a compact subset of $U$.

I would apply Urysohn's lemma twice.

$K_1$ is a compact subset of $U_1 := \Omega \setminus K_2$. By Urysohn's lemma, there exists a continuous $g_1: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that

- $0 \leq g_1(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$;
- $g_1(x) = 1$ for all $x \in K_1$;
- $\text{supp}(g_1)$ is a compact subset of $U_1$.

Similarly, $K_2$ is a compact subset of $U_2 := \Omega \setminus K_1$, so by Urysohn's lemma, there exists a continuous $g_2 : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that

- $0 \leq g_2(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$;
- $g_2(x) = 1$ for all $x \in K_2$;
- $\text{supp}(g_2)$ is a compact subset of $U_2$.

Finally, we define the function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ f(x) = g_1 (x) - g_2(x).$$

Observe that

- $f$ is continuous, since $ g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous.
- $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$, since $0 \leq g_1(x) \leq 1$ and $0 \leq  g_2(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \Omega$.
- $f_1(x) = 1$ for all $x \in K_1$, since $g_1(x) = 1$ and $g_2(x) = 0$ for all $x \in K_1$.
- $f_1(x) = -1$ for all $x \in K_2$, since $g_1(x) = 0$ and $g_2(x) = 1$ for all $x \in K_2$.
- $\text{supp}(f)$ is compact, since $\text{supp}(f)$ is a closed subset of the compact set $\text{supp}(g_1) \cup \text{supp}(g_2)$.

Comment: Which version of Urysohn's lemma are you using here? I am familiar with one of the versions of it for normal topological spaces where any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by continuous functions. Is it the modified version for locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: My version states that if $\Omega$ is locally compact and Hausdorff and $K \subset U \subset X$ with $K$ compact and $U$ open, then there exists a continuous function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ with $|f| \leq 1$, with $f|_K = 1$ and with $\text{supp}(f)$ compact in $U$.

Comment: I've edited my answer to simplify the argument, and also I've stated exactly which version of Urysohn's lemma I'm using.

Comment: If you know the "Urysohn lemma" for normal space, you can obtain this version of Urysohn lemma for l.c.s just by taking one-point compactification of the space (recall that compact Housdorff spaces are normal)

Comment: Even more stronger result holds. We can actually take $f \in C^{\infty} (\Omega).$ Consider the open cover $\{\Omega \setminus K_1, \Omega \setminus K_2 \}$ of $\Omega.$ Let $\{\psi, \varphi\}$ be the partition of unity corresponding to this cover i.e. $\text{supp}\ (\psi) \subseteq \Omega \setminus K_1$ and $\text{supp}\ (\varphi) \subseteq \Omega \setminus K_2.$ Then since $\psi + \varphi = 1$ on $\Omega,$ it follows that $\psi = 0$ on $K_1$ and $\varphi = 0$ on $K_2.$ Hence, $\varphi = 1$ on $K_1$ and $\psi = 1$ on $K_2.$ Now just define $f : = \varphi - \psi.$